# Correct way to upload and save image in Laravel with vue.js and Element-ui

Tags: laravel, element-ui

I'm making a recipe book and I want the recipes to have the choice to upload images, I'm using Element-UI in this project and they have an [upload component](https://element.eleme.io/1.4/#/en-US/component/upload). However, I'm not super sure how to use it correctly. I'm basing this on some code I found but it's not really working the $request I receive in the controller always has the `image: null`. I'm using `$intertia.post` but I could change to `$http.post` if needed.

This is what I'm trying

```
<el-upload
    class="avatar-uploader"
    action="/api/vendors/fake-upload"
    accept="image/*"
    :show-file-list="false"
    :on-success="handleAvatarSuccess"
    :before-upload="beforeAvatarUpload">
    <img v-if="form.image" :src="form.image" class="avatar">
    <i v-else class="el-icon-plus avatar-uploader-icon"></i>

    <div class="buttonImage">
        <el-button v-if="form.image" class="img-button mt-1" type="warning">
            Change Picture
        </el-button>
    </div>
</el-upload>
```

Relevant data() in my vue `<script>`

```
loadingImage: false,
imageFile: null,
form: {
    name: '',
    description: '',
    image: ''
},
```

These are the methods that go with the `<el-upload>`

```
handleAvatarSuccess(res, file) {
    this.form.image = URL.createObjectURL(file.raw);
    this.loadingImage = false;
},
beforeAvatarUpload(file) {
    this.imageFile = file;

    const isJPG = file.type === 'image/jpeg';
    const isLt2M = file.size / 1024 / 1024 < 2;

    if (!isJPG) {
        this.$message.error('This picture must be a JPG!');
    }
    if (!isLt2M) {
        this.$message.error('This image is bigger than 2MB!');
    }

    this.loadingImage = true;
    return isLt2M && isJPG;
},
```

This is how I'm sending it to the controller

```
submit() {
    this.$refs.form.validate((valid) => {
        if (valid) {
            this.loading = true;
            if (!this.form.id) {
                this.$inertia.post(this.baseUrl, {
                    name: this.form.name,
                    description: this.form.description,
                    category: this.category,
                    steps: this.steps,
                    ingredient: this.ingredient,
                    measurements: this.measurements,
                    image: this.imageFile
                }).then(
                    () => {
                        this.recipe = this.$page.recipe;
                        this.$message({
                            type: 'success',
                            message: 'Created correctly.'
                        });
                        this.loading = false
                    },
                    (res) => {
                        this.$message.error(parseError(res)[0]);
                        this.loading = false;
                    })
            } 
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        this.reset();
    });
},
```

What's the correct way to do this, or is there an easier way?

Comment: I see that you have `form.image` and `imageFile` in your state. `imageFile` doesn't look to get touched at all, but it is the one being posted. Maybe try setting the posted image to this instead: `image: this.form.image`.

Comment: @chunterb I forgot to add 2 methods, see my update